# magento broken shopping rule page

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, admin, backend

I have a problem on magento backend that I am not sure what is happening. Shopping cart price rule was working completely fine, but suddenly the rule page look like this:

[screenshoot of shopping rule page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opiN9.png)

The content of each tab is loaded inside the tab div itself instead of on the content area on the right. Content area is completely empty.

No code was touched in relation with promotions code, or admin/core code at all. I don't see any issue on console or not js code loaded. This is the only page affected (shopping cart price rule page), catalog rule works fine as well as any other with same structure (product page, customer page and such).

I was recently playing around with promotion too much, creating, deleting and editing. And solved a 500 issue on cart page increasing php memory limit. Not sure if related with this issue.

On apache logs it only displays the following when I access that page:

> client denied by server configuration: /www/app/etc/local.xml

Could someone help me in where to look in order to solve this issue or have a hint about what could be the issue?

I am completely lost with this one. Magento version 1.7.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the issue. It was a extension related.

Recently I had some issues on cart page and at some point I disabled a promotion extension (Amasty shipping rules) though magento backend, on system/advanced extensions list.

Seems like the extension is disabled but still used on promotion page, adding the structure for the feature but not showing what is supposed to show (because is disabled) and breaking the layout.

Enabling again the extension or removing the extension on files avoid the issue.

Answer (score 0):

1) clear the cache maybe you made a update and your cache is wrong. you can clear in the admin side clear all the types, or erase all inside /www/var/cache

2) clear the page history in your browser, all is fine but your machime show that weird.

3) after that check the browser console, because is a css problem, maybe a file is lost or change the permitions.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I did the first point, clear cache, several times, I will check the rest see if something change.

Comment: None of the points worked, but I have found the issue. I will post it now. Thanks for the help